# How to use list/tuple one element at a time in a function?

Tags: python

I'm trying to make some code that lets me use a function to get the price of items and sum them together quickly.

So a simplified version of my code currently looks like this:

```py
#Header = {Item, Price, Service Tax}
Dairy = {'Milk': [2.30, 0.16, 'Yes'],
         'Butter': [4.50, 0.32, 'No']}
Cart = []
Cart.append('Milk')
Cart.append('Butter')
Collective = []
Collective.append(Cart[0])
print(sum(Collective))
```

This results in either `Unhashable error` or nothing being printed at all, when I'm looking for the sum of 2.30 and 4.50.

Comment: `Cart.append(Milk)` does not work as `Milk` is not defined

Comment: please provide a reproducible example with error logs.

Comment: You need to access a dict and a list, do you know how to do that? By doing `Dairy['Milk']` you get the corresponding list `[2.30, 0.16, 'Yes']` and by doing `Dairy['Milk'][0]` you get the first element of that list which is `2.30`...

Answer (score 1):

Just try using this code:

```
print(sum([sublist[0] for sublist in Dairy.values()]))
```

Output:

```
6.8
```

Comment: I can't do that as my Code has more than just those two and I'm trying to use the list function to process it all one by one as I can even have multiple of the same item in there

Comment: You cannot have the same item multiple times as key in dictionary

Comment: @Ram The `Cart` list can...

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that `Dairy` contains lots of stuff, but you only want some information, whose keys are in `Cart`, then you can do this:

```py
#Header = {Item, Price, Service Tax}
Dairy = {'Milk': [2.30, 0.16, 'Yes'],
         'Butter': [4.50, 0.32, 'No'],
         'other': [42.50, 0.42, 'No']}
Cart = []
Cart.append('Milk')
Cart.append('Butter')

Collective = [Dairy[item][0] for item in Cart]
print(sum(Collective))
```

Output: `6.8`